# Changing the colours of the fields depending on a formula?

Tags: formula-field, custom-field, fields, if

I have two number fields on opportunity layout. A and B. I want to create a formula field and when A>B the formula field will be red or just an indication that people will notice it right away when they are creating an opportunity that A should not be greater than B. When A<B it will be just regular without any indication. How could I do this?

IF ( A > B, "BAD", "GOOD") This is what I did to display text, but some colors or other indications will be better for someone to not miss and notice it easier compare to a displayed text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [IMAGE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.useful_advanced_formulas_image_links.htm&type=5) formula field to accomplish this.

Your formula will be as below

```
IF (A > B, 
      IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif", "red", 40,40),
     IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif", "green", 40, 40)
 )
```